# CONDA Base Env load error / NUMPY: ImportError: DLL load failed

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, environment

Just installed miniconda on `C:\Anaconda 3` and ran `conda install numpy` unsing the Anaconda shell (defaults to conda base as env).

If I run the Anaconda command prompt and type `python >> import numpy` all works fine.

If I open a normal command window and got to `c:\Anaconda3` and run `python >> import numpy` this fails (error below).

I have checked `sys.path` and they are the same on both CMD windows. The only solution is to run on the normal CMD window doing: `c:\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda activate base` and then run `python >> import numpy`.

I had Miniconda installations in the past that did not have this issue so I am surprised to suddenly have to activate the environment. I thought the base environment is loaded by default but it seems as if this is not the case and i have to force that.

The error I get is:

```
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in <module>

    from . import _distributor_init
  File "c:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 34, in
<module>
    from . import _mklinit
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I found that I could run from the command line: `C:\Anaconda3\python.exe C:\Anaconda3\cwp.py C:\Anaconda3 C:\Anaconda3\python.exe` and then run `import numpy` and that will work. The cwp.py file is as follows:

```
# this script is used on windows to wrap shortcuts so that they are executed within an environment
#   It only sets the appropriate prefix PATH entries - it does not actually activate environments

import os
import sys
import subprocess
from os.path import join, pathsep

from menuinst.knownfolders import FOLDERID, get_folder_path, PathNotFoundException

# call as: python cwp.py PREFIX ARGs...

prefix = sys.argv[1]
args = sys.argv[2:]

new_paths = pathsep.join([prefix,
                         join(prefix, "Library", "mingw-w64", "bin"),
                         join(prefix, "Library", "usr", "bin"),
                         join(prefix, "Library", "bin"),
                         join(prefix, "Scripts")])
env = os.environ.copy()
env['PATH'] = new_paths + pathsep + env['PATH']
env['CONDA_PREFIX'] = prefix

documents_folder, exception = get_folder_path(FOLDERID.Documents)
if exception:
    documents_folder, exception = get_folder_path(FOLDERID.PublicDocuments)
if not exception:
    os.chdir(documents_folder)
sys.exit(subprocess.call(args, env=env))
```

PS: If you wonder "why is this needed if you can simply activate base"? When using xlwings for instance the script calls python.exe (without activating an environment first, even if I thought that using the python.exe on the root folder meant you did not need to activate base environment). This is troublesome as I get the error when I try to load numpy.

Thanks!

Comment: @orangeInk yes, path is the same in both environments. It is not just activating base that works but running the cwp.py script with C:\Anaconda32 as parameter

Answer (score -1):

It's a DLL error. caused because of missing DLL file. download files from [here](http://www.mediafire.com/file/nk6d1qwfpiumqkv/Msvcp71.dll-And-Msvcr71.dll-files_by_harjot_pawra.zip/file)

Go to C:/windows/system32 and /Windows/SysWOW64 folder .just paste those files

If asked just replace files

Comment: Cannot be that because running `conda activate base` and then `python >> import numpy` works. It is when simply running `python.exe` and then typing `import numpy` (without activating the environment) that the library load fails. Typing `import numpy` on the spyder console also works fine.